# Pass input parameters to ruby-written shell?

Tags: ruby, shell, prompt, readline

I'm trying to write a shell in Ruby (using `readline`), implementing some custom commands. To create the correspondence between given input and methods that are defined in an external module I'm using an hash like this

```
hash = {
  'command_1' => method(:method_1),
  'command_2' => method(:method_2)
}
```

And once I got the user input I pass it to the hash calling the method associated with the command-key

```
hash[input.to_s].()
```

My questions are: how can I handle variants of the same command? (e.g. for the `help` command give different output depending if a flag is given, something like `help -command_1`)

How can I pass parameters to methods in the hash? (e.g. pass to an `open` command the file to be opened like `open file_name`)

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: You can pass arguments through the `.()` method call.

Comment: Might want to build a true CLI instead using something like [`thor`](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor), [`slop`](https://github.com/leejarvis/slop) , [`commander`](https://github.com/commander-rb/commander) and [many more](https://lab.hookops.com/ruby-cli-gems.html)

Comment: As said above, there are entire frameworks written around CLIs in ruby - this will likely make your life much easier than trying to reinvent the wheel! But if you really want to build your own (or to have full control of how the entire application works), the fundamental approach - in many languages, including ruby - is to use `ARGV`.

Comment: Ruby also provides [`ARGF`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/ARGF.html), which also handles streaming input. Also, for some slightly more advanced out-of-the-box tooling, there is a library called [`optparse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) in ruby's standard library.

Comment: I've written a simple shell like this in ruby, using readline, it's at https://github.com/kontena/kontena-plugin-shell

Comment: Thanks all for the replies. I've quickly looked at **thor** documentation but I've only found a way of passing args on calling (something like `my_program -args1 -args2` ), but I haven't found a way to create a prompt that accept commands until user exit (to give you an idea, something like the _msfconsole_ of metasploit). Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

While that might work if you wrangle it enough, the easy way is this:

```
hash = {
  'command_1' => :method_1,
  'command_2' => :method_2
}

send(hash[input.to_s])
```

The `send` method allows dynamic dispatch which is way easier than trying to deal with `method`.